# Print Only When Condition is True in R

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements, arima, random-seed

This solution  [Automate Seed as a Vector Instead of an Integer in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65268535/i-want-to-set-and-automate-seed-as-a-vector-instead-of-an-integer-in-r/65268730#65268730)

```
library(forecast)
SEED_vector <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19)
arima_order_results = data.frame()
for (my_seed in SEED_vector){
  set.seed(my_seed)
  ar1 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model=list(ar=0.2, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 1)
  ar2 <- auto.arima(ar1, ic ="aicc")

  arima_order = arimaorder(ar2)
  arima_order = t(as.data.frame(arima_order))
  # Print the arima order.
  print(arima_order)
  # This line of code is just if you want to store the results in a dataframe
  arima_order_results = rbind(arima_order_results,arima_order)
}
```

I will only want `arimaorder` of (1, 0, 0) to be printed instead of all

I tried this and jammed with error:

```
SEED_vector <- 1:100
arima_order_results <- data.frame()
while(TRUE){for (my_seed in SEED_vector) {set.seed(my_seed)
    ar1 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model=list(ar=0.2, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 1)
    ar2 <- auto.arima(ar1, ic ="aicc")
    if(all(arimaorder(ar2)==c(1,0,0))) print(arima_order_results)
    arima_order = arimaorder(ar2)
    arima_order = t(as.data.frame(arima_order))
    # Print the arima order.
    print(arima_order)
    # This line of code is just if yo uwant to store the results in a dataframe
    arima_order_results = rbind(arima_order_results,arima_order)

}}
```

I want something like this:

```
#arima_order14 1 0 0 
#arima_order39 1 0 0 
#arima_order47 1 0 0
```

Comment: Your second sentence is not clear to me, please write it as an answer with `MWE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps, this helps

```
SEED_vector <- 1:200
arima_order_results <- data.frame()
flag <- TRUE
i <- 1
seed_out <- c()
while(flag){ 
 
     set.seed(SEED_vector[i])
     ar1 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model=list(ar=0.2, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 1)
     ar2 <- auto.arima(ar1, ic ="aicc")
     if(all(arimaorder(ar2)==c(1,0,0))) {
     
        #print(arima_order_results)
        print(paste0('arimaorder', SEED_vector[i], ' ' , 
              paste(arimaorder(ar2), collapse=" ")))
         seed_out <- c(seed_out, SEED_vector[i])
        
        }
       
     arima_order = arimaorder(ar2)
     arima_order = t(as.data.frame(arima_order))
     
     
     arima_order_results = rbind(arima_order_results,arima_order)
     
     i <- i+1
     if(i == length(SEED_vector)) {
     
      flag <- FALSE
     }

 }
```

-output

```
#[1] "arimaorder14 1 0 0"
#[1] "arimaorder152 1 0 0"
#[1] "arimaorder165 1 0 0"
```

Now, we check the vector

```
seed_out
#[1]  14 152 165
```

and it can be written to a file with `write.table` or `cat`

```
cat(seed_out, file = 'seed_file.txt')
```

Comment: Yes, I want the `arima_order` with their corresponding seed labels printed with

Comment: @DanielJames i guess the update should help.

Comment: I need to write the output of this result into a dataframe then to .csv file

Comment: @DanielJames YOu meant the `print` should to written to a file?.  In that case, you want change the `print` to `cat` and specify the `file` with `append = TRUE` from second line of `cat`

Comment: yes, I am dealing with tens of thousand rows, unlike my **MWE**

Comment: @DanielJames I would say change the `print` to `cat(paste0('arimaorder', SEED_vector[i], ' ' , 
              paste(arimaorder(ar2), collapse=" ")), file = "file1.txt", append = TRUE)`

Comment: what I really need in it is the seed number in vector form just like the one I supplied called `SSED_vector

Comment: @DanielJames Can you please check my update

Comment: @DanielJames I created a `seed_out` vector to store the output off the seed number that matches the criteria.  It can be written to a file with `cat`