# Elegant Way to Print Coefficients of Set of Simulated AR(1) Along with there Seeds in R

Tags: r, arima, seeding

I got a solution to Automate Seed as a Vector Instead of an Integer in R [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65268535/i-want-to-set-and-automate-seed-as-a-vector-instead-of-an-integer-in-r/65268730#65268730) and another solution to filter the true `arimaorder` of the simulated data that follows `ARIMA(1, 0, 0)` along with the seeds that produce them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65270719/print-only-when-condition-is-true-in-r/65270772?noredirect=1#comment115392647_65270772) also. Out of the seeds that produce the specified `ARIMA` order, I want to `print` the `ar coefficients` of them all along with there seeds.

I tried this:

```
SEED_vector <- c(14, 152, 165,528, 539, 1091, 1240, 1259, 1314, 1425, 1481, 1552)
arima_order_results = data.frame()
for (my_seed in SEED_vector){
    set.seed(my_seed)
    ar1 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model=list(ar=0.2, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 1)
    ar2 <- auto.arima(ar1, ic ="aicc")
    arr <- ar2$coef
    print(arr)
    arima_order_results = rbind(arima_order_results,arr)
}
```

I got this as an output:

```
#ar1  intercept 
#-0.6920070  0.4209332 
       #ar1  intercept 
#-0.7202459 -0.3036454 
       #ar1  intercept 
#-0.8971835 -0.4130711 
      #ar1 
#0.8749406 
       #ar1 
#-0.7520381 
       #ar1  intercept 
#-0.8363416  0.3014670 
       #ar1  intercept 
#-0.7016283  0.4847039 
       #ar1  intercept 
#-0.6667556  0.6719526 
       #ar1  intercept 
#-0.6481393 -0.3125167 
       #ar1  intercept 
#-0.6084819 -0.9350262 
       #ar1  intercept 
#-0.8985071  0.4437974 
       #ar1  intercept 
#-0.7552149  1.2879873
```

**Instead of `ar1` in my `R` output I will rather prefer the seed number that produces the coefficient**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
library(forecast)
library(dplyr)
SEED_vector <- c(14, 152, 165,528, 539, 1091, 1240, 1259, 1314, 1425, 1481, 1552)
arima_order_results = data.frame()
for (my_seed in SEED_vector){
  set.seed(my_seed)
  ar1 <- arima.sim(n = 10, model=list(ar=0.2, order = c(1, 0, 0)), sd = 1)
  ar2 <- auto.arima(ar1, ic ="aicc")
  arr <- as.data.frame(t(ar2$coef))
  arr <- cbind(data.frame(seed=my_seed),arr)
  print(arr)
  arima_order_results = bind_rows(arima_order_results,arr)
}
```

Output:

```
arima_order_results
   seed        ar1  intercept
1    14 -0.6920070  0.4209332
2   152 -0.7202459 -0.3036454
3   165 -0.8971835 -0.4130711
4   528  0.8749406         NA
5   539 -0.7520381         NA
6  1091 -0.8363416  0.3014670
7  1240 -0.7016283  0.4847039
8  1259 -0.6667556  0.6719526
9  1314 -0.6481393 -0.3125167
10 1425 -0.6084819 -0.9350262
11 1481 -0.8985071  0.4437974
12 1552 -0.7552149  1.2879873
```